# how to launch and login a rich client(eclipse plugin RCP) application through command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a rich client application built on eclipse plugin and swt. It has an .exe file through which it can be launched. First window is login window in that application.
I want to launch and log into this app automatically so that automated unit testing can be done.
Is there any way to do it through command line?

Comment: Look at [SWTBot](http://eclipse.org/swtbot/)